# Are all libraries from github safe?

Tags: android, github

I want to use this github library to implement in-app purchases: https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3

Is it possible he inserted some code to steal license keys or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all code on Github is safe. However, a library with 2000 stars is almost certainly not doing anything malicious. If it were, somebody else would have looked through the code by now and found the nefarious content.

Answer (score 1):

> Are all libraries from github safe?

No, not really. Like all software, they can have vulnerabilities.

Although GitHub has put in place measures to cub Vulnerabilities in libraries, some might still have.

The good thing about open source is you can always look through the source code yourself and if you spot any suspicious code, you can easily not integrate it in your app.